# Sobre VB 2010 Express o Visual Studio 2023: Ubicación por defecto del directorio Resources

Tags: visual-studio, vb

En este momento, puntualmente, me encuentro con la dificultad de levantar un archivo gráfico alojado en *Resources* y cargarlo en un PictureBox. Puedo hacerlo fácilmente usando la ruta específica (literal o absoluta, del tipo "C..." etc), pero no con la ruta dinámica que es lo que sirve.
Me han sugerido el siguiente código:

```
Imports System.IO

 Sub CargarImagenEspecifica(ByVal nombreImagen As String)
        ' Obtiene la ruta del directorio de tu aplicación
        Dim rootDirectory As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

        ' Concatena la ruta del directorio "Resources" a la ruta del directorio de tu aplicación
        Dim resourcesDirectory As String = Path.Combine(rootDirectory, "Resources")

        ' Concatena el nombre de la imagen especificada al directorio de recursos
        Dim imagenPath As String = Path.Combine(resourcesDirectory, nombreImagen)

        ' Verifica si el archivo de imagen existe
        If File.Exists(imagenPath) Then
            ' Carga la imagen en el PictureBox
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(imagenPath)
        Else
            ' Maneja el caso en el que el archivo de imagen no existe
            MessageBox.Show("La imagen especificada no se encontró.")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Pero obtengo mal la ruta (*Resources* como subdirectorio de "*bin\Debug*") pero *Resources* (creado por la plataforma) es un directorio del mismo nivel que 'bin'. Entiendo que podría mover *Resources* a *Debug*, pero, con seguridad, no es una solución correcta.
Agradecería que me orienten en este punto (y seguramente en otros, porque, reitero: soy un aficionado que no programa desde hace 20 años y tengo pendiente un proyecto y la mejor intención de aprender).

> Estoy reaprendiendo después de 20 años de no programar nada (lo hacía en VB6), estoy bastante perdido.

Comment: Hola. por favor, tomate un minuto para hacer el [tour] y entender como funciona el sitio. Esto no es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. simplemente, aceptando la respuesta, votandola positivo, o dejando un comentario si la respuesta sirvio aunque no sea la ideal, estas diciendo gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo de "Resources" no lo he ocupado nunca, pero te puedo decir como lo hago yo.

Creo una carpeta para imágenes, digamos que se llama `img`. Luego pongo las imágenes en dicha carpeta.

Selecciono TODAS las imágenes (manteniendo la tecla shift presionada) y presiono F4 para abrir el cuadro de propiedades

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En propiedades coloco:

- Acción de compilación: Contenido
- Copiar en el directorio de salida: Copiar siempre

Estas 2 configuración hace que cada que vez que compilas (ya sea en modo debug o release) se copien los archivos (y las carpeta que los contienen) al nivel del .exe

Luego para cargar la imagen, simplemente:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("img/minilogo.png")
```

Evidentemente puedes validar si la imagen existe usando `If File.Exists` tal como tu lo tienes, pero eso ya es decisión de cada uno